# Javascript change color

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="Javascript">
            function changecolor(var c)
            {
            document.body.style.background=c;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="300" height="100" align="center" border=2>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseout=changecolor("transparent") onmouseover=changecolor("red")>red</td>
                <td onmouseout=changecolor("transparent") onmouseover=changecolor("green")>green</td>
                <td onmouseout=changecolor("transparent") onmouseover=changecolor("blue")>blue</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not getting the change of color.
Can someone please help...!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please use jsfiddle.net to show your example

Comment: functions don't have var in them `function changecolor(var c)` should be `function changecolor(c)`

Comment: You should surround your onmouseout/onmouseover statements with ''. That is, `onmouseout=changecolor("transparent")` should be `onmouseout='changecolor("transparent")'`

Comment: Why so many identical answers ? When one is made, no need to add other ones...

Comment: @dystroy let just close this post as we know OP got the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should write

```
function changecolor(c)
```

instead of

```
function changecolor(var c)
```

Because when you write `var c` in the function declaration, the browser will declare a new variable in the scope of your function. So when you then use the c variable it will return undefined since you didn't assigned some data to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In ur javascript functions no need to declare type of parameters

so change

```
function changecolor(var c)
```

to

```
function changecolor(c)
```

this will solve ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="Javascript">
        function changecolor(c)
        {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor=c;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="300" height="100" align="center" border=2>
        <tr>
            <td onmouseout="changecolor('white')" onmouseover="changecolor('red')">red</td>
            <td onmouseout="changecolor('white')" onmouseover="changecolor('green')">green</td>
            <td onmouseout="changecolor('white')" onmouseover="changecolor('blue')">blue</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <script language="Javascript">
            function changecolor(c)//remove var
            {
            document.body.style.background=c;
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<table width="300" height="100" align="center" border=2>
    <tr>
        <td id="redcolor" onmouseover="change_red()" onmouseout="change_color()">red</td>
    <td id="greencolor" onmouseover="change_green()" onmouseout="change_color()">green</td>
        <td id="bluecolor" onmouseover="change_blue()" onmouseout="change_color()">blue</td>
    </tr>
 </table>

 <script>  
     function change_red()
         {
             document.getElementById("redcolor").style.color="red";
         }

     function change_green()
        {
     document.getElementById("greencolor").style.color="green";
 }

function change_blue()
{
    document.getElementById("bluecolor").style.color="blue";
}

function change_color()
{
document.getElementById("redcolor").style.color="#000";
document.getElementById("greencolor").style.color="#000";
document.getElementById("bluecolor").style.color="#000";
}
</script>  

</body>
```